# Passport JS, Функция logout не работает как положено. (NodeJS, ExpressJS + ReactJS)

Tags: node.js, express, passport

Делаю аутентификацию по PassportJS, стратегия passport-google-oidc. Сама аутентификация, редирект, установление сессии работает отлично, но функция логаута не работает как надо.

Роут на бэкенде

```js
authRouter.post('/logout', async (req, res, next) => {
    req.logout(req.user, (err)=> {
        if (err) return next(err);
    })
    req.session.destroy((err) => {
        res.clearCookie('connect.sid');
    });
})
```

Хэндлер на запрос на фронте:

```js
const handlerLogOut = async () => {
        await axios.post('/api/auth/logout', {withCredentials: true})
            .then(res => {
                console.log('response ', res);
            })
    }
```

Сначала делал роут на бэкенде только с помощью метода `req.logout()` и отправлял на клиент `res.send(req.user)` - бэкенд присылает `req.user === null`, `req.isAuthenticated() === false`, то есть `user` очищается, но потом сервер снова восстанавливает сессию и `req.user === user` и `req.isAuthenticated() === true`.

Сделал по совету https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50454992/req-session-destroy-and-passport-logout-arent-destroying-cookie-on-client-side, добавив `req.session.destroy()` и `res.clearCookies()`, но сейчас появляется следующая ошибка:

```
<MyDisk>\<My Folder>\<Project Folder>\server\node_modules\passport\lib\sessionmanager.js:83
    req.session.regenerate(function(err) {
                ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'regenerate')
    at Statement.<anonymous> (<MyDisk>\<My Folder>\<Project Folder>\server\node_modules\passport\lib\sessionmanager.js:83:17)
    at Statement.<anonymous> <MyDisk>\<My Folder>\<Project Folder>\server\node_modules\connect-sqlite3\lib\connect-sqlite3.js:119:32)
```

Судя по всему sessionmanager пытается восстановить сессию из моего session store, но сталкивается с тем, что req.session удален.

Сессия на expressjs выглядит так:

```js
app.use(session({
    secret:'review-website',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    store: new sessionStore({db: 'sessions.db', dir: './'})
}));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил вопрос, следующим образом:
Убрал `req.destroy.session()`

```
authRouter.post('/logout', async (req, res, next) => {
req.logout(req.user, (err)=> {
    if (err) return next(err);
})
res.clearCookie('connect.sid');
res.send({isAuth: req.isAuthenticated(), user: req.user})})
```

На фронте:

```
await axios.post('/api/auth/logout',{}, {withCredentials: true})
        .then(res => {
            console.log('response ', res);
            setUser(res.data.user)
        })
        .catch(e=> console.log(e))
```

Вместо

```
await axios.post('/api/auth/logout',{withCredentials: true})
        .then(res => {
            console.log('response ', res);
            setUser(res.data.user)
        })
        .catch(e=> console.log(e))
```